# swing wait 3 second inside while loop

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have program get data from mysql db and show it in textfield.

I want show one record every 3 second.

this is my code,

```
Connection conn = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jointdb";
    String dbUsr = "root";
    String dbPass = "a12345";
    try{
    String sql= "select * from eridb  ";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl,dbUsr,dbPass);
    st = conn.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
   // textField1.setText("enter text here");
    while(rs.next()){
        String value = rs.getString("id");
        textField1.setText(value);          
    }

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    try {
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        st.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have used sleep, but the program is hanging ( no benefits)

please assist me
thank you ...

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder  No, for updating a GUI (which must be done on the EDT) it is easier to use `javax.swing.Timer`..

Comment: i am tell please assist me by wite code do not give me hints @AdrianB.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i am tell please assist me by wite code do not give me hints

Comment: *"do not give me hints"*  So I'm your servant now?  Yes *master*..  Put your feet up and pig out on pizza and coke while I put that code together for you.  In fact, I'll make it easy, give me your instructors email addy and I'll send it straight through to them..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do background jobs that take some time in Swing, you should use [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) ([Oracle's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), although not really that helpful... ).

For scheduling the task, you can go, as @Andrew Thompson said with `javax.swing.Timer` (a somewhat [better tutorial from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) this time.